# How to stop append string in forEach?

Tags: node.js

Here is what I got:

I try to send requests to a service, that's what `otherFunction()` do. Each request use different parameters loaded from `config.events`. Then I want to append a randomParam to each event.

```
config = { events: [...] }
for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    config.events.forEach(element => {
      // Get a random string
      str = '&randomParam=' + Random.word(10)
      element.url += str
      console.log(element.url)
      otherFunction(element)
      // the element.url keep append random word 100 times, but I expect only one word append for each loop
  })
}
```

I'd trid create a const var, using deep copy (JSON parse/stringify) and `delete element.url` and add it again. But none of it could solve my problem.

Actually, I did not know what exactly happend in my code and how this caused.

Current Result:

```
https://example.com/exampleApi/index.html?testParam=123&randomParam=rbveostvie
https://example.com/exampleApi/index.html?testParam=123&randomParam=rbveostvie&randomParam=bjanckrbjc
https://example.com/exampleApi/index.html?testParam=123&randomParam=rbveostvie&randomParam=bjanckrbjc&randomParam=rbuunvtdux
```

Expect Result:

```
https://example.com/exampleApi/index.html?testParam=123&randomParam=rbveostvie
https://example.com/exampleApi/index.html?testParam=123&randomParam=bjanckrbjc
https://example.com/exampleApi/index.html?testParam=123&randomParam=rbuunvtdux
```

Comment: I am afraid you description is a bit confusing. What is the purpose of the outer `for` loop? Can you also share an example of an example output?

Comment: Sorry for my misdescribe. @UmairSarfraz `for` loop is used to invoke `otherFunction` 100 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the random string assignment out of the inner `forEach` loop.

```
var config = {
  events: [
    {
      url: "foo"
    },
    {
      url: "baz"
    }
  ]
};


for (let i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
  var str = "&randomParam=" + Random.word(10);

  config.events.forEach(element => {
        otherFunction(Object.assign({}, element, { url: element.url + str }));

  });
}
```

For each *i* out of *n=100* iterations, your inner `forEach` loop would iterate *k=config.events.length* times. By moving the random string outside the inner `forEach` loop, you would ensure that you generate *n* random strings instead of *n * k* random strings.

**Edit**

As per OP updated description, the actual problem is that `element.url` is being mutated. On every iteration, it will append the random string to the previously set url. Hence, I have updated my answer to include `Object.assign({}, element, { url: element.url + str })` which will make sure no object in `config.events` gets mutated.

Please see below a working example:

```js
function getRandomString() {
  return Math.random()
    .toString(36)
    .substring(7);
}

var config = {
  events: [{
      url: "foo"
    },
    {
      url: "baz"
    }
  ]
};

function otherFunction(element) {
  console.info(element.url);
}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  var str = "&randomParam=" + getRandomString();

  config.events.forEach(element => {
    otherFunction(Object.assign({}, element, {
      url: element.url + str
    }));
  });
}
```

Comment: @Bruce I just saw your updated question. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `config.events` is an array of 100 elements, and you want to add a random string to every `element.url`.

You don't need two loops, one is enough. Remove that outer loop, and you'll get what you want

**--EDIT--**

According to the comment the author posted later, the outer loop should be moved to wrap the `otherFunction` call.

```
config = { events: [...] }

config.events.forEach(element => {
  // Get a random string
  str = '&randomParam=' + Random.word(10)
  element.url += str
  for(let i = 0; i < 100; i++){
    otherFunction(element)
  }
})
```

Comment: I do want to add a random string to every `element.url`. But I also needs to invoke `otherFunction(elementWithRandomString)` 100 times

Comment: Still not works on my situation: 1) I need to call `otherFunction` 100 times with 100 random tail; 2) though I move `forEach` to outer loop, I still got endless randomtail on url.